# Logging user input if meets condition

Tags: javascript, logging, input

I am working on a discount code feature.
Here's my code:

```js
var discount = document.getElementById("disc");

function greets(){
    var input = discount.values

    if(input == "Hey"){
        console.log("heyback");
    }
}
```

```css
html {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ff8177 0%, #ff867a 0%, #ff8c7f 21%, #f99185 52%, #cf556c 78%, #b12a5b 100%);
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Purchase A Product!</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
<body>
    <h1>Purchase A Product</h1>
    <form action="https://formsubmit.co/samyking2011@gmail.com" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="name" required placeholder="Name?">
        <input type="email" name="email" required placeholder="Email?">
        <input type="text" name="product" id="prodbuy" placeholder="What would you like to buy?" required>
        <input type="text" name="quantity" id="quant" placeholder="Quantity?">
        <input id="disc" placeholder="Enter Discount Codes Here(Optional)">
        <button id="discapply" type="submit" onclick="greets">Apply Promo Codes</button>
        <button type="submit" id="sub">Send</button>
        </form>
</body>
<script src="./script.js"></script>
```

My question is, how can I log something if a user inputs something into a text box?

Note: I cannot use `.value` instead of `.textContent`. Any help with that would also be appreciated.

Comment: Where are you using `.textContent`? Why won't it let you use `.value`?

Comment: You forgot the `()` to call the function `onclick="greets()"`

Comment: code won't work if user enters hey.  onclick should be greets(), to get value should be discount.value

Answer (score 0):

You would want to hook into that element's [input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oninput), like so:

```js
const discount = document.getElementById("disc");

discount.addEventListener('input', ev => {
   if (ev.target.value === 'Hey') {
       console.log('heyback');
   }
});
```

```css
html {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #ff8177 0%, #ff867a 0%, #ff8c7f 21%, #f99185 52%, #cf556c 78%, #b12a5b 100%);
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<h1>Purchase A Product</h1>

<form id="f">
    <input id="disc" />
</form>
```